# Date difference calculation from time stamp saved in firebase node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my application, which uses android studio and firebase database, a seller can subscribe to a particular shop (ex. Bakery) for two years once he pay the registration fee. At the time of registration, I am saving the registration date and time to firebase realtime database as shown in figure:

[image].

After two years, I want to show a toast message to seller that subscription period expired. For that I need to subtract date of registration (which I can take from fire base node) and current date, and I know how to get current date as shown below

```
  Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    SimpleDateFormat currentDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy"); 
    currentDate = currentDateFormat.format(calForDate.getTime());
    Calendar calForTime = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    SimpleDateFormat currentTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    currentTime = currentTimeFormat.format(calForTime.getTime()); 
    long timestamp= System.currentTimeMillis();
```

I just want to subtract current date from above code with registration date from firebase node and check whether 730 days (365*2) are over or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you store the timestamp for the bakery, you don't need a calendar. Instead you can simply start from the current time in millis and subtract two years worth of milliseconds from that:

```
long nowInMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
long twoYearsInMs = 2 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
long twoYearsAgoInMs = nowInMs - twoYearsInMs;
```

You can then use this `twoYearsAgoInMs` to query the database with something like:

```
DatabaseReference sellerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("SellerRegFee");
Query query = sellerRef.orderByChild("Bakery/timestamp").endAt(twoYearsAgoInMs);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEven(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot sellerSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("seller", sellerSnapshot.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have few questions, 1. I am saving time stamp in database, and you told that since I use time stamp for the bakery (Shop type) , I don't need a calendar but time stamp is not used in your code,  then what is the relevance of time stamp.  2. Once two year over,  I need to notify to seller who registered for bakery that subscription ended through a toast message, where I will put the toast. I like to have an 'if' condition for toast and other following steps, where I put that condition.

Comment: Did you try my code yet? What happened when you did?

Comment: App crashed when I used Query query = sellerRef.orderByChild("Bakery/timestamp").endAt(twoYearsAgoInMs);
, there are lot of methods and codes in my application , explaining all of them will be out of scope of this question. It will  work only in the way I wrote the logic. I just want to use a condition using if else,  if the number of days are over 730, it has to toast a message and return to payment activity , for that I need to subtract registration date with current date, I like to know how I can subtract two days or subtract two time stamps , kindly tell me if you know it

Comment: I was able to find the solution using a youtube video.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZRY42R9f-0  The detailed code is available in there.

Comment: The code in my answer shows how to subtract two timestamps. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯